# Can't stop countdown after minimize screen

Tags: android

Android Studio 4.0

```
  private var countDownTimer: CountDownTimer? = null
 countDownTimer = object : CountDownTimer(waitingTimeRemainingMills, COUNT_DOWN_INTERVALE_MILLSECONDS) {
            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                minutesAndSeconds = String.format(getString(R.string.countdown_time_format),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)
                                - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)))
                waitingCountdownDateTextView.setText(minutesAndSeconds);
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    Log.d(TAG, "initToolbarAndTopContainer:\nonTick, millisUntilFinished = $millisUntilFinished")
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                //mTextField.setText("done!")
            }
        }.start()


override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        countDownTimer?.cancel()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        countDownTimer?.start()
    }
```

After start activity the the method `onTick` success call every second. Nice.
After minimize screen call method `onPause` , but `onTick` not stop.It's call every one second.

Answer (score 0):

Inside onStop(), save the value of *waitingTimeRemainingMillis* in a separate variable, say *temp* (which has the whole class as the scope) and then **cancel** the CountDownTimer object. Inside onResume, store the value of *temp* in *waitingTimeRemainingMillis* and start the CountDownTimer.

Comment: Not help. onTick method not stop

Comment: The whole countdown should be stopped once you call the cancel() method. Just store that time in a temporary variable. Inside onResume(), begin the new countdown with that temporary value.